# Is there a way to summary 2 column in 2 different gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I'm currently working on Web Page C# and I have 2 gridview as shown below :

```
Gridview 1
-------------------------------
|  ID  | Name | Polis |  TSI  |
|------|------|-------|-------|
|   1  | John |  10%  |   x   |
|   2  | Alex |  24%  |   x   |
|   3  | Rita |   5%  |   x   | 
-------------------------------

Gridview 2
-------------------------------
|Premi |Materai| Biaya | Total |
|------|-------|-------|-------|
| 100  |   6   |  30%  |   y   |
| 200  |   6   |  10%  |   y   |
| 300  |   6   |  25%  |   y   | 
-------------------------------
```

I'd like to know, how do I get X and Y, while :

> **TSI = Premi * Polis**

and

> **Total = Polis + TSI + PREMI + MATERAI + BIAYA**

This is my code so far.

```
protected void gv1_CustomUnbound(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDataEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.FieldName == "TSI")
            {
                int premi = Convert.ToInt32(gv2.GetSelectedFieldValues("Premi").ToString());             
                int polis = Convert.ToInt32(gv1.GetSelectedFieldValues("Polis").ToString());
                e.Value = premi * polis;
            }
        }

protected void gv2_CustomUnbound(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDataEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.FieldName == "Total")
            {
                int premi = Convert.ToInt32(gv2.GetSelectedFieldValues("Premi").ToString());
                int polis = Convert.ToInt32(gv1.GetSelectedFieldValues("Polis").ToString());
                int tsi = Convert.ToInt32(gv1.GetSelectedFieldValues("TSI").ToString());
                int materai = Convert.ToInt32(gv2.GetSelectedFieldValues("Materai").ToString());
                int biaya = Convert.ToInt32(gv2.GetSelectedFieldValues("Biaya").ToString());
                e.Value = Polis + TSI + PREMI + MATERAI + BIAYA
            }
        }
```

Thanks so much. Appreciated

Comment: how are these two tables related? do you want a cartesian product or you have a common field in both tables??

Comment: It's not table. Its Gridview. And they're not related at all. Both Gridviews using different dataSource.And its not about cartesian product.